# How to boot ubuntu from initramfs prompt?

Tags: boot

A program was running on my ubuntu for about 2 days, and then I found my ubuntu to be completely frozen. I had to restart it with power key. Now, it won't load  up. I can see `advanced options for ubuntu` and it looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3HNP-jA8JZuQU5XM2lkam9kRDA). 
Selecting `recovery mode` would end up in a initramfs promt which looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3HNP-jA8JZub2M4eE9zbFVYN1k). 
I don't know what to do and googling haven't help that much.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!